# Django GEO MySQL query error: 'WKTAdapter' object has no attribute 'translate'

Tags: python, mysql, django, gis

I have model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    poly = models.PolygonField()
```

Django settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
```

And when i try to filter `MyModel` by `poly` field such as:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
MyModel.objects.filter(poly__contains=Point(23.23452, 45.123444))
```

I got error `AttributeError: 'WKTAdapter' object has no attribute 'translate'`

As you can see i use Python 3.6.0, Django==1.10.6, PyMySQL==0.7.11, mysqlclient==1.3.10. 
And MySQL is 5.7.16

Is there anyway to make it work? Or i need to extrack all `poly` values and then process it in pure Python?

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 232, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 110, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 164, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 143, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 118, in _escape_args
    return tuple(conn.literal(arg) for arg in args)
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 118, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(conn.literal(arg) for arg in args)
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 821, in literal
    return self.escape(obj, self.encoders)
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 814, in escape
    return escape_item(obj, self.charset, mapping=mapping)
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 27, in escape_item
    val = encoder(val, mapping)
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 110, in escape_unicode
    return u"'%s'" % _escape_unicode(value)
  File "/Users/ailove/Work/breeders/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 73, in _escape_unicode
    return value.translate(_escape_table)
AttributeError: 'WKTAdapter' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

Answer (score 1):

So i went through debugging and not very good news.

Default adapter for gis fields is `WKTAdapter`(for my infrastructure) which have two attributes `srid` and `wkt`. In `wkt` it stores `str` that actually needs to be used in query.

So we have `WKTAdapter` object that needs to be translated to `str`, and [`pymysql`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) can't do that.

And there is only one simple choice is to use query that couldn't be created and run it as raw SQL.

```
SELECT mymodel.id  # other fields
FROM mymodel
WHERE MBRWithin(mymodel.poly,
                ST_GeomFromText('POINT (23.23452, 45.123444)'));
```

And then do whatever you like, convert it to `MyModel` instances or use your raw values.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I get this error on "makemigrations", how did you manage to migrate models at first place? @vishes_shell

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you could monkey patch `WKTAdapter` by placing this e.g. in your django `settings` module:

```py
from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.adapter import WKTAdapter  # noqa


def wkt_translate_monkey(self, table):
    return str(self).translate(table)


WKTAdapter.translate = wkt_translate_monkey
```

There is an issue on the matter, that was closed due to inactivity:
https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/525

I will try to revive it.